# Filtering data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm matching a user in a list of users as follows:

```
export async function getLoginData(uid) {
  let loginData;

  const usersRef = await database.ref('users');
  const snap = await usersRef.once('value');

  snap.forEach((item) => {
    const itemVal = item.val();
    if (itemVal.uid === uid) {
      loginData = itemVal;
    }
  });

  return loginData;
}
```

Style-wise, I'm not a fan of this. I'd much rather do a filter for the matching:

```
loginData = snap.filter((item) => item.val().uid === uid);
```

But the filter method is not available in the snapshot. Is there a way to write more clean, one line retrievals of data from Firebase? Or does it always have to be a forEach and a callback as I have above?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on sorting and filtering data? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: Thanks Doug. Yes, I should've read this properly. I'm new to Firebase, as you can tell. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before worrying about the style of your current filtering approach, it's probably better to consider its performance. You're downloading all data under the `/users` node to then filter out anything where `item.val().uid <> uid`. Such client-side filtering wastes your user's bandwidth.

You should instead use Firebase's built-in querying capabilities where possible. In this case it seems quite simple:

```
let loginData;

const usersRef = await database.ref('users');
const snap = await usersRef.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(uid).once('value');

snap.forEach((item) => {
  const itemVal = item.val();
  loginData = itemVal;
});
```

In this case you still need to loop. Since a query can potentially match multiple child nodes, the code needs to deal with this situation.

If you are certain that each user node has a unique UID, you should consider storing the user data with that UID as the key (instead of another generated key):

```
users
  uid1
    name: "user2878765"
  uid2
    name: "Frank van Puffelen"
```

Storing the user data under the key automatically ensures that the UID is unique and makes it that you can look up the user's data without requiring a query. That also means you don't need a `forEach()` anymore:

```
let loginData;

const usersRef = await database.ref('users');
const snap = await usersRef.child(uid).once('value');

const itemVal = snap.val();
loginData = itemVal;
```

That also makes it easier to return the correct promise from your function:

```
export async function getLoginData(uid) {
  const snap = await database.ref('users').child(uid).once('value');

  return snap.val();
}
```